# Swagger requestbody not allowed

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add the request body to a swagger file, but when I use requestBody, it keeps saying `Additional properties not allowed: requestBody` I tried multple `-in` parameters like this

```
      parameters
        - in: body
          name: email
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
        - in: body
          name: password
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
```

but then it says `Operation cannot have multiple body parameters` So I'm not sure how to reference all the req.body values. Also what if I had multiple body parameters and an /:id path as well?
I'm still really new to swagger so I appreciate any help with this.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Hello World App during dev, should point to your local machine
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
paths:
  /user/signup:
    x-swagger-router-controller: user
    post:
      description: signup POST
      operationId: signup
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: email
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
        - in: body
          name: password
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success got all the listings
          schema:
            $ref: "/definitions/User"
        "500":
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string

  /user/login:
    x-swagger-router-controller: user
    post:
      description: Login request
      operationId: login
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: login
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Login"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success got all the listings
          schema:
            $ref: "/definitions/Login"
        "500":
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string

definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      email:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      instagramName:
        type: string
      over21:
        type: boolean
      role:
        type: string
      fullName:
        type: string
      address1:
        type: string
      address2:
        type: string
      city:
        type: string
      state:
        type: string
      zip:
        type: string
      passwordCreated:
        type: string

  Login:
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple `in: body` parameters, you have them all defined already in the User schema (each request has just one body anyways).  That is exactly how it should be done. Just remove the second 'body' and maybe rename the other one:

```
parameters:
  - in: body
    name: user
    description: The user to create.
    schema:
      $ref: "#/definitions/User"
```

If you require a path parameter you can define it as `in: path`. You need to add it to the path itself as well:

```
paths:
  /user/signup/{id}:
    x-swagger-router-controller: user
    post:
      description: signup POST
      operationId: signup
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          description: User id
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: The user to create.
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/User"
```

In contradiction to `in: body` you can have multiple `in: path` parameters. Path parameters must include `required: true`.